# Memoize return value of custom hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom React hook something like this:

```
export default function useLocations(locationsToMatch) {
  const state = useAnotherHookToGetStateFromStore();
  const { allStores } = state.locations;

  const allLocations = {};
  allStores.forEach((store) => {
    const { locationId, locationType } = store;
    const isLocationPresent = locationsToMatch.indexOf(locationId) !== -1;
    if (isLocationPresent && locationType === 'someValue') {
      allLocations[locationId] = true;
    } else {
      allLocations[locationId] = false;
    }
  });

  return allLocations;
}
```

When I use above hook inside my React component like this:

```
const locations = useLocations([908, 203, 678]) // pass location ids
```

I get a max call depth error due to infinite rendering. This is because I have some code inside my component which uses `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => { // some code to re-render component on change of locations
   }, [locations])
```

So I tried to wrap my return value in `useLocations` hook inside a `useMemo` like this:

```
export default function useLocations(locationsToMatch) {
  const state = useAnotherHookToGetStateFromStore();
  const { allStores } = state.locations;

  const allLocations = {};
  const getStores = () => {
    allStores.forEach((store) => {
      const { locationId, locationType } = store;
      const isLocationPresent = locationsToMatch.indexOf(locationId) !== -1;
      if (isLocationPresent && locationType === 'someValue') {
        allLocations[locationId] = true;
      } else {
        allLocations[locationId] = false;
      }
    });
    return allLocations;
  };

  return useMemo(() => getStores(), [locationsToMatch, state]);
}
```

But this still causes infinite re-rendering of the consuming component. So how can I return a memoized value from my custom hook `useLocations` to prevent infinite re-rendering?